# How to change the Text color of the action Bar using Material Theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

I override the BackGround Color of the ActionBar from the style.xml 
This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Action bar -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

The code from main activity is here :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ActionBar mActionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTitles = firstItem.getTitle(); //setting the title of the first item
    /**
     * Action Bar customization
     */
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    //Latest
    mActionBar.setTitle("  Latest"); // set the first title
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // hide tha app icon from the action bar
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

The problem is that I can't see the text of the action bar if i set the color from style.xml . Futhermore i can't use things like :

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/row_child_menu_title</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/row_child_menu_title</item>
```

the result is the same. The text is being disappeared and only the menu icons and the toggle icon are visible

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use toolbar not actionbar

Comment: @tyczj but i am using theme holo for APIs < 21 is this a problem?

Comment: well if you want to use the `colorAccent` and the new stuff like that yes since that only works with toolbar

Answer (score 0):

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff9501"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
```

Activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```